# Using expo secure-store to store and retrieve user credentials and populate email & password fields

Tags: reactjs, expo

I'm building a mobile app on both iOS and Android, and I'm attempting to store user credentials with expo's secure-storage. I can successfully store them, as tested with console.log, however what I want to achieve is populating my email and password fields on the app with the stored credentials, so that users can simply select one field and both become populated, leading to a quicker login.

I've placed `textContentType='email/password'` and `autoComplete='email/password'` in my `TextInput` tags but I'm unsure how to propery achieve and ensure that the two fields are populated with the stored information.

```
    const authHandler = async () => {
    if (true) {
    // sign up
    } else {
    try {
    // login
      let password = localState.inputValues.password;
      await save('emailAddress', userEmail);
      await save('password', localState.inputValues.password);
      await save('userinfo', JSON.stringify({userEmail, password}));
      await getValueFor('emailAddress');
      await getValueFor('password');
      await getValueFor('userinfo');
}
    
  async function save(key, value) {
    await SecureStore.setItemAsync(key, value);
  }

  async function getValueFor(key) {
    let result = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(key);
    if (result) {
      console.log(" Here's your value  \n" + result);
    } else {
      console.log('No values stored under that key.');
    }
  }

return (

          <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: "8%" }}>
            <TextInputWrapper
              onFocus={() => {
                setEmailSelected(true);
              }}
              onBlur={() => {
                setEmailSelected(false);
              }}
              label="Email"
              onChangeText={(input) => inputChangeHandler("email", input)}
              placeholder="me@example.com"
              value={localState.inputValues.email}
              textContentType='emailAddress'
              autoComplete='email'
            />
          </View>
        </View>
        {/* password input */}
        <View
          style={{
            paddingVertical: "2%",
            flexDirection: "row",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: "8%" }}>
            <TextInputWrapper
              onFocus={() => {
                setPwSelected(true);
              }}
              onBlur={() => {
                setPwSelected(false);
              }}
              label="Password"
              onChangeText={(input) => inputChangeHandler("password", input)}
              placeholder="At least 6 characters required"
              secureTextEntry
              value={localState.inputValues.password}
              textContentType='password'
              autoComplete='password'
            />
          </View>
        </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in docs is written -> value "The value to store. Size limit is 2048 bytes." and its string
My proposal is to use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse methods.

```js
async function save(key, value) {
  const preparedDataToSave = JSON.stringify(value)
  await SecureStore.setItemAsync(key, preparedDataToSave);
}
const userCredentials = {id:2,name:"test"}
save("userCredentials", userCredentials)
```